# uwsgi spooler Error

Tags: uwsgi, spooler

I just want to know the feature of uswgi spooler. And I make a demo as the following link:
[enter link description here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html)

My uswgi.ini is following:

```
[uwsgi]
django_projects_dir = /home/zzb/Documents/djangoFiles
my_project = mysite2
chdir = %(django_projects_dir)/%(my_project)
pythonpath = %(django_projects_dir)
module = django.core.handlers:WSGIHandler()
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(my_project).settings
master = true
processes = 4
spooler = %(chdir)/mytasks
import = task
socket = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

After I run the command
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

Something wrong happened. The Error is following:

```
[zzb@zzb mysite2]$ uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini 
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
[spooler directory] access(): No such file or directory [core/spooler.c line 25]
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your spooler directory does not exist